# Sending double click to Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I want that a double-click on an HTML table row selects the record.

I found the element to send a left-click, but I could not send a double-click. I checked that there was no mouse event control / attribute for the selection and I think it's because it was using a jquery / java function.

I cannot share the website. I know it can be done because someone has, but they are not sharing it.

The code that I believe is related to the function we need

```
/* double click on table row */
jQuery(tableId ).on('dblclick', ' tbody tr',function() {
if(isAutoNextEnabled!=null && isAutoNextEnabled=='Y'){
createAutoNextListNew(oTable, tableName, this);
}
window[functionName](this);
});
```

Since I cannot share the URL, I found an alternative https://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse-2.html

Here is a website that detect our clicks. It captures a single left-click, but does not capture a double-click.

I know there is a firevent option for the website provided, but the website where I need this function does not.

This works for a single-click, from the website (https://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse-2.html), it captures the left-click once:

```
set ta = objie.getElementsByTagName
for each x in ta
    if x = [[our target ]]
    x.click
    end if
next x
```

It **does not work** when I double-click

```
for each x in ta
    if x = [[our target ]]
        x.doubleclick
    end if
next x
```

or

```
for each x in ta
    if x = [[our target ]]
        x.doubleclick
    end if
next x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following shows adding htmlEvents (click and dblclick) and then firing them using your linked page

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ClickTest()

    Dim evtClick  As Object, evtDblClick As Object, ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://unixpapa.com/js/testmouse-2.html"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set evtClick = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
        Set evtDblClick = .document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")

        evtClick.initEvent "click", True, False
        evtDblClick.initEvent "dblclick", True, False

        With .document.querySelector("#link")
            .dispatchEvent evtClick
            .dispatchEvent evtDblClick
        End With
        With .document.querySelector("textarea")
            Do
            Loop While .innerText = vbNullString
            Debug.Print .innerText
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: that was brilliant . and by far the most comprehensive solution with workable example . great thanks and you are helpful as always

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the jquery api for double click?

```
https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. had lookup many api and all did'nt workout